# Volley NoConnectionError : tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, android-volley

I have been using volley to make HTTPS request to server, and I am getting this error -

```
{ what=1 when=-253ms obj=com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x64565f00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1409443E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1290 0x62d71518:0x00000003) }
```

I have removed SSLV3 protocol error using the code here

```
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78187
```

and was testing on Samsung DUOS.

Do anyone know how to avoid this error.